# Getting authentication failed error with postgresql from command line

Tags: postgresql, centos

When i try to login from command line like this

```
psql -h dbserver -U testuser test
```

then i get this error

```
psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "testuser"
```

This is my

> nano -w /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                               ident
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          password
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               ident
host    all     all     192.168.0.1/24  password
```

Comment: do you have identd running?

Comment: Have you Grant login permission to that user ?

Comment: Change line `local all all ident` to `local all all md5` and then follow Craig's answers, or run identd.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't specify a non-default user with `-U` in `psql` when using `ident` authentication. You won't be running `psql` as that user, so auth will fail.

You must either use `sudo -u testuser psql test` or change `pg_hba.conf` so that authentication (at least for `testuser` on the db `test`) uses `md5` password authentication, and set a password for `testuser` with `ALTER USER ... PASSWORD` if they don't have one already.

Answer (score 1):

I saw the following errors in `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_log/postgresql-Wed.log`:

> LOG:  provided username (DB_USER) and authenticated username
>   (SHELL_USER) don't match FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user
>   "DB_USER"

The solution in my case was to change all the authentication methods in `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf` to **md5**

Answer (score 1):

With abovementioned, there can be two reasons for this issue
- testuser not existing
- wrong password or authentication failure for the user.

Here is what I did to resolve this in Windows:

1. **Check via pgAdmin**: Go to your programs and search for pgAdmin and run. Typically this will be running at http://127.0.0.1:51865/browser/

Check for the Login/Group Roles tab under Server "PostgreSQL".
Check if the user is existing. You can also do this by logging to "postgres" user via command **"psql -U postgres"**  and running command **"\du"**

If user testuser does not exist, create it.

2. Change the authentication methods in pg_hba.conf to md5. 
   Alternatively,
   change the password for the user with the command:
   ALTER USER ... PASSWORD.