# How to run postgresql from Command line and know available Databases in Windows

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

I am very new to postgreSQL and struggling to create a connection in my Eclipese.

Here is what I have done till now:

1. Installed DBeaver plugin for eclipse from marketplace.
2. Installed PostgreSQL version 10 from https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/
3. Now I attempt to create a connection in Eclipse but I get an error "FATAL: password authentication failed for user "testuser"

I checked through a similar thread (
[Getting authentication failed error with postgresql from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531527/getting-authentication-failed-error-with-postgresql-from-command-line?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
) but could not resolve the issue.

Could you please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To connect the PostgreSQL via Command line you have to install a PostgreSQL provided tool called "psql" if not installed already.

Then use the below command to connect to PostgreSQL database.

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres
```

Explanation:

```
localhost: is the hostname of machine where PostgreSQL is installed.
5432 : is the default PostgreSQL port
postgres : is the username of to connect to DB
```

Solution for your issue:

```
FATAL: password authentication failed for user "testuser"
```

As error message specified, either user not exists on database or the password that you supplied to connect is incorrect. Re-verify your user and password, and try again.

All the best.

Comment: psql is installed but running `psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres ` gives `psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
     `